Need help to multi-thread in my Minecraft clone
I am currently creating a Minecraft clone in C and OpenGL. I have implemented a chunk loading system however this would result in freezing as new chunks are loaded as the main thread is having to wait for the chunks terrain to be generated, therefore I am now trying to implement a second thread that will wait until a chunk is ready to be generated and generate its terrain.
My current idea is that the world stores a linked list for the chunks and a queue to store the chunks that need to be generated (each would store a pointer to the chunks memory that was allocated). Then when the load chunk function was ran it creates a new chunk that isn't visible so that you cant see the terrain before it's generated, it also adds this to the chunks to be generated queue.
Then the generator thread would wait until the chunks to generate queue has a chunk in, get that chunk (and remove from queue) and generate and update it along with making it visible.
I have tried implementing this my self with a separate thread however I'm not sure if the while (true) is really the best idea. I've also tried to use mutexes but am struggling to understand when to lock and unlock, if order matters and also in the generator thread I think it may be locking it forever but I'm not sure. I also tried to use a thread condition but still no luck.
If anyone could guide me on the best approach for my idea it would be very helpful. Thanks.
The GitHub repository if needed: https://github.com/Brumus14/minecraft-clone/tree/5d6614e62d80d54b2c535261b25c29c131590cec
#include "world.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "noise1234.h"
#include "../math/math_util.h"

pthread_mutex_t chunks_to_generate_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t chunks_to_generate_count_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t chunks_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t chunks_count_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int get_chunk_index(world *world, vector3i position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < world->chunks_count; i++) {
        chunk *chunk = linked_list_get(&world->chunks, i);

        if (vector3i_equal(chunk->position, position)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

void generate_chunk_terrain(world *world, chunk *chunk, int stage) {
    if (stage == 0) {
        for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIZE_Z; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_SIZE_Y; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE_X; x++) {
                    vector3i position;
                    vector3i_init(&position,
                                  chunk->position.x * CHUNK_SIZE_X + x,
                                  chunk->position.y * CHUNK_SIZE_Y + y,
                                  chunk->position.z * CHUNK_SIZE_Z + z);

                    block_type type = BLOCK_TYPE_EMPTY;

                    if (position.y < (noise3(position.x * 0.03,
                                             position.z * 0.03, world->seed)) *
                                             16 -
                                         8) {
                        type = BLOCK_TYPE_STONE;
                    } else if (position.y <
                               (noise3(position.x * 0.03, position.z * 0.03,
                                       world->seed)) *
                                   16) {
                        type = BLOCK_TYPE_DIRT;
                    }

                    chunk->blocks[z][y][x] = type;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // better ore generation
    // use octaves and make noise generator abstraction
    if (stage == 1) {
        for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIZE_Z; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_SIZE_Y; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE_X; x++) {
                    vector3i position = {chunk->position.x * CHUNK_SIZE_X + x,
                                         chunk->position.y * CHUNK_SIZE_Y + y,
                                         chunk->position.z * CHUNK_SIZE_Z + z};

                    if (chunk->blocks[z][y][x] == BLOCK_TYPE_DIRT &&
                        world_get_block(world,
                                        (vector3d){position.x, position.y + 1,
                                                   position.z}) ==
                            BLOCK_TYPE_EMPTY) {
                        chunk->blocks[z][y][x] = BLOCK_TYPE_GRASS;
                    } else if (chunk->blocks[z][y][x] == BLOCK_TYPE_STONE) {
                        if (noise4(position.x * 0.2, position.y * 0.2,
                                   position.z * 0.2, world->seed) > 0.6) {
                            chunk->blocks[z][y][x] = BLOCK_TYPE_COAL;
                        } else if (noise4(position.x * 0.2, position.y * 0.2,
                                          position.z * 0.2,
                                          world->seed * 1.419198) > 0.6) {
                            chunk->blocks[z][y][x] = BLOCK_TYPE_DIAMOND;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void *generation_thread_main(void *world_arg) {
    world *world_pointer = (world *)world_arg;

    // copy the data so dont have to keep chunks to generate locked for main
    // thread
    while (true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_count_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);

        if (world_pointer->chunks_to_generate_count > 0) {
            chunk *chunk = queue_dequeue(&world_pointer->chunks_to_generate);
            world_pointer->chunks_to_generate_count--;

            generate_chunk_terrain(world_pointer, chunk, 0);
            generate_chunk_terrain(world_pointer, chunk, 1);
            chunk_update(chunk);
            chunk->visible = true;
            printf("Chunk Generated - %d, %d, %d\n", chunk->position.x,
                   chunk->position.y, chunk->position.z);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_count_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_mutex);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void world_init(world *world) {
    tilemap_init(&world->tilemap, "res/textures/atlas.png",
                 TEXTURE_FILTER_NEAREST, 16, 16, 1, 2);

    world->chunks_count = 0;
    linked_list_init(&world->chunks);

    world->chunks_to_generate_count = 0;
    queue_init(&world->chunks_to_generate);

    world->seed = random_range(0, 100);

    pthread_create(&world->generation_thread, NULL, generation_thread_main,
                   world);
    pthread_detach(world->generation_thread);
}

void world_load_chunk(world *world, vector3i position) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);

    if (get_chunk_index(world, position) != -1) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_count_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_mutex);

        return;
    }

    chunk *new_chunk = malloc(sizeof(chunk));
    chunk_init(new_chunk, position, &world->tilemap);
    new_chunk->visible = false;

    linked_list_insert_end(&world->chunks, new_chunk);
    world->chunks_count++;

    queue_enqueue(&world->chunks_to_generate, new_chunk);
    world->chunks_to_generate_count++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_mutex);
}

// remove chunks from chunks to generate if have moved out of render distance
// before generated
void world_unload_chunk(world *world, vector3i position) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);

    int chunk_index = get_chunk_index(world, position);

    if (chunk_index == -1) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_count_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_mutex);

        return;
    }

    linked_list_remove(&world->chunks, chunk_index);
    world->chunks_count--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_mutex);
}

void world_draw(world *world) {
    texture_bind(&world->tilemap.texture);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);

    for (int i = 0; i < world->chunks_count; i++) {
        chunk_draw(linked_list_get(&world->chunks, i));
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_to_generate_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_count_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&chunks_mutex);
}

// use mipmapping
block_type world_get_block(world *world, vector3d position) {
    // rename to chunks loaded
    vector3i chunk_position = {floor(position.x / CHUNK_SIZE_X),
                               floor(position.y / CHUNK_SIZE_Y),
                               floor(position.z / CHUNK_SIZE_Z)};

    int chunk_index = get_chunk_index(world, chunk_position);

    if (chunk_index == -1) {
        return BLOCK_TYPE_EMPTY;
    }

    chunk *chunk = linked_list_get(&world->chunks, chunk_index);

    vector3i block_chunk_position = {mod(floor(position.x), CHUNK_SIZE_X),
                                     mod(floor(position.y), CHUNK_SIZE_Y),
                                     mod(floor(position.z), CHUNK_SIZE_Z)};

    return chunk->blocks[block_chunk_position.z][block_chunk_position.y]
                        [block_chunk_position.x];
}

void world_set_block(world *world, block_type type, vector3d position) {
    vector3i chunk_position = {floor(position.x / CHUNK_SIZE_X),
                               floor(position.y / CHUNK_SIZE_Y),
                               floor(position.z / CHUNK_SIZE_Z)};

    int chunk_index = get_chunk_index(world, chunk_position);

    if (chunk_index == -1) {
        return;
    }

    chunk *chunk = linked_list_get(&world->chunks, chunk_index);

    vector3i block_chunk_position = {mod(floor(position.x), CHUNK_SIZE_X),
                                     mod(floor(position.y), CHUNK_SIZE_Y),
                                     mod(floor(position.z), CHUNK_SIZE_Z)};

    chunk->blocks[block_chunk_position.z][block_chunk_position.y]
                 [block_chunk_position.x] = type;

    chunk_update(chunk);
}


you should really consider reading a book or two about concurrency, for one you don't really lock arbitrary amounts of code, you only lock a single operation. like adding something to the queue, and mostly locks are hidden inside the containers and are not for everyone to see and manipulate ..... as for your question you need a [mcve] and the question is not answerable in its current state.

I am struggling to find a question here, but that's a lot of mutexes that you're using. Given that you're always locking all four, you could use a single mutex. As Ahmed mentioned, try implementing a queue data structure that has an internal lock that is acquired while removing from or adding to the queue (and released afterwards).

I have to disagree with @AhmedAEK.  When you lock, the scope of the lock often needs to be multiple lines of code, spanning many operations.  But that scope should be kept as narrow as possible, which sometimes is as narrow as a single operation.
